# hostname "imgur.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js` but it is configured correctly on my next.config.js, what is wrong?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to upload an image stored in MongoDB.

```
{ '_id': 1, 'type': 'shirt', 'price': 20, 'pic': 'https://imgur.com/6D53pAF'}
```

The error is saying my next.config.js is not configured properly but it is configured exactly how it would suggest.

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          protocol: "https",
          hostname: "imgur.com",
          port: '3000',
          pathname: ""},
      ],
    },
  }
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way of doing this?

I originally had the image stored over my github in an issues section on my project and it worked but once I change databases it will no longer pull up the image.